# Eclipse does not launch (Ubuntu) : JVM terminated. Exit code=2

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu, environment-variables

1. I install ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64bit)
2. After that Install Eclipse Luno Standard for 64bit
3. Install Jdk and follow all the step for setting jdk using following link,

   http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux
4. Then After I enable to start my eclipse it giving me a following Error,

   VM terminated. Exit code=2

   ```
    /usr/bin/java
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
    -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    -Xms256m
    -Xmx1024m
    -jar   /home/eheuristic/Ecclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415- 2008.jar
    -os linux
    -ws gtk
    -arch x86_64
    -showsplash  /home/eheuristic/Ecclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140925- 0400/splash.bmp
    -launcher /home/eheuristic/Ecclipse/eclipse/eclipse
    -name Eclipse
    --launcher.library  /home/eheuristic/Ecclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1. 200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so
    -startup /home/eheuristic/Ecclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
   --launcher.appendVmargs
   -exitdata 208017
   -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
   -vm /usr/bin/java
   -vmargs
   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
   -Xms256m
   -Xmx1024m
   -jar  /home/eheuristic/Ecclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
   ```

I so much try to solve setting Environment variable but can't do, help me one suggest to how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my Stupid Solution ,

I trying install jdk that is support for 32 bit.

I downloads new **jdk1.8.0_25 for 64 bit** and follow the step, i got solutions.

Answer (score 17):

First, I strongly recommend you use the webupd8 ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Then to set it

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
```

The advantage is ease of updates.

Answer (score 1):

write in eclipse.in on the top of the file

```
-startu
-vm
/usr/local/jdk/jre/bin
```

change path according to your system

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error. Solved it by:

sudo update-alternatives --config java

I started "using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode" - that was option 4, and it worked fine.

I am using Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2).

Hope it helps someone somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly how to solve your problem, go to search and put in environment, a prompt will come up and ask you to"edit environmental variables for your account" click that and a window will pop up. there will be the current paths which are running on the top (you should have your jdk version running mine is 1.8) and on the bottom part there will be paths too choose from. select (on the bottom part) the java path and delete it, then click okay. it should work

Comment: .bashrc file will be there in you home folder, go there and set ->

#jdk path
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

Comment: you are having jdk problem, if you are having more than two jdk installed remove both of tghem and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when trying to run Eclipse and Android Studio on Ubuntu with Java 9 .
Solution: Install Java 8

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

and set it as default

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

and voilà.