# Eclipse error JVM terminated. Exit code=1 /usr/Java70/jre/bin/java

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jvm

I get a error like

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/Java70/jre/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

My java version is:

```
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6470sr9-20150417_01(SR9))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20150406_242981 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR9_20150406_1443_B242981
JIT  - tr.r11_20150401_88894
GC   - R26_Java726_SR9_20150406_1443_B242981_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20150406_242981)
JCL - 20150414_02 based on Oracle 7u79-b14
```

My eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms512m
-Xmx512m
```

Linux version:

```
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
```

Why am I get that error and how can I solve it?

Ran java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar

```
java: cairo-misc.c:380: _cairo_operator_bounded_by_source: Assertion `NOT_REACHED' failed.
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "abort", detail "" at 2015/06/30 21:51:32 - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using '/root/Desktop/core.20150630.215132.10911.0001.dmp' in response to an event
JVMPORT030W /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern setting "|/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp %s %c %p %u %g %t e" specifies that the core dump is to be piped to an external program.  Attempting to rename either core or core.11074.

JVMDUMP010I System dump written to /root/Desktop/core.20150630.215132.10911.0001.dmp
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/root/Desktop/javacore.20150630.215132.10911.0002.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to /root/Desktop/javacore.20150630.215132.10911.0002.txt
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '/root/Desktop/Snap.20150630.215132.10911.0003.trc' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Snap dump written to /root/Desktop/Snap.20150630.215132.10911.0003.trc
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "abort", detail "".
```

Comment: Usually, there's a log file created in this case with details. Please post the log

Comment: where is the log file located?

Comment: either in the .metadata folder of your workspace or the config directory with in the eclipse directory

Comment: what would be the name of the log file? anything in specific I should look for. there is no metadata folder in my workspace

Comment: Is there anything printed to the console? What happens when you do `java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar`?

Comment: Nothing is printed on console. When I do that your way - java jar command as you mentioned, that loads eclipse and updated the error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that whenever navigating to any workitem on RTC, that error occurred and eclipse crashed. Basically the UI did not appear or half appeared. This was solved by adding the following to the last line in `eclipse.ini`:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false
```

Comment: This is a known problem with some RHEL versions and the "cairo graphics" plugin in question apparently - disabling it seems to apply to a number of Eclipse-based IBM products aside from RTC.

Answer (score 16):

This might happens if multiple Java instances have been installed. Run the following command -

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Then choose the correct java path and re-run the eclipse application.

Answer (score 13):

First, I strongly recommend you use the `webupd8 ppa`, use following commands:

1.`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`
2.`sudo apt-get update`
3.`sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

Then to set it:

4.`sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle`

The advantage is ease of updates.

Comment: Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736164/eclipse-does-not-launch-ubuntu-jvm-terminated-exit-code-2/26750783#26750783

Answer (score 4):

Try to put your java package in eclipse.ini

If you are using Ubuntu, the java path generaly is /usr/lib/jvm. See:

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-x-openjdk-amdxx/bin/java
-vmargs
```

Remember to put -vmargs after -vm

Answer (score 1):

So even I faced the same error when i installed the **eclipse Oxygen** into my system. I did the whole setup and configured it accordingly but when I tried to open the **eclipse.desktop** through MENU options or even tried running eclipse through the terminal, I encountered the error as above. So here what I did :-

1) I modified  **eclipse.ini** by adding :- 
**Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false** (still no luck , I faced the same error)

2) Updated the java version by adding it alternatively by the adding these commands in the terminal

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

Hope it helps!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This error had occurred to me , I have tried all the solutions above .
I had also tried removing the .ini file too . even that didnt help
CONCLUSION
There are some eclipse versions which support java version like 7,8,9
Hence u have to download eclipse according to ur jdk
eclipse neon : java8
eclipse oxygen : java8
eclipse mars : java7
all the java versions have upward compatibility
[image: Image from eclipse official page]

Answer (score 0):

- Open eclipse.ini file.
- Delete the line "-vmargs"
- Save it