# Eclipse keeps crashing when running project

Tags: eclipse, crash

My Eclipse keeps crashing when I run my project, and sometimes even the browser itself too.
I don't know why.

Here's the error I get:
[image: eclipse cash error]

What can I do to remedy this?

Comment: Questions must provide a [minimum, reproducible example](/help/mcve). Many possible causes, as an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146089/eclipse-error-jvm-terminated-exit-code-1-usr-java70-jre-bin-java

Comment: Does it still happen with the current release?

Comment: please post the error, as text, not an image.